# Calculate the value of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}\cos(\ln(x))}{x^2+1}\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm asked to evaluate the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}\cos(\ln(x))}{x^2+1}\,dx$.

I tried defining a funcion $f(z)=\frac{e^{(1/2+i)\operatorname{Log}(z)}}{z^2+1}$, taking $\operatorname{Log}$ with a branch cut along the positive real axis: ($\operatorname{Log}(z)=\ln(|z|)+i\arg(z))$.

Using residue theorem with the "pacman" contour.

However when trying to bound the integral around a small circle around $0$, I cannot conclude it converges to $0$.

My attempt was $|\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}f|\leq 2\pi\epsilon|e^{(0.5+i)(\ln|\epsilon|+i\theta))}|\frac{1}{\epsilon^2-1}\leq C\epsilon^{-0.5}.$

I'd love it if someone could either suggest a different way to bound the integral around $0$ of this function, or maybe suggest an easier complex function to work 
with.

Edit:

The wonderful "Related" algorithm of this site managed to link me to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866402/calculate-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sqrtx-cos-big-lnx-bigx?rq=1)
Looking at it , a more general statement is proved, but the proof fails when we have $\alpha=0.5+i$  (The circle around $0$ doesn`t converge to $0$ by the proof given there, as a matter of fact any $\alpha$ with $Re(\alpha)>0$ would fail.)

Comment: Are you forced to use complex analysis?

Comment: It's a practice problem for the residue theorem but I`d like seeing different approaches aswell!

Comment: I could be wrong, but I doubt you want the branch cut directly on the path of integration! Usually, in complex analysis, you choose branch cuts to avoid the contour altogether.

Comment: You`re correct, using a contour of upper half circle with a branch cut along the negative imaginary axis would be more simple, but both yield the same result eventually (And both have the same problem of convergence around 0 )

Comment: I tried to evaluate your integral using a different approach without using contour integration (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3088089/on-the-evalution-of-an-infinite-sum)) but got stuck on an infinite sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Adrian suggested, define $\log z =\log |z|+i\arg(z)$ where $\arg(z)\in (0,2\pi)$ and let the contour be a keyhole contour. 
[image]

Then
$$
\left|\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{e^{(1/2+i)\log z}}{z^2+1}\,dz\right|\le \int_{\gamma_R}\frac{e^{1/2 \log|z|-\arg(z)}}{R^2-1}\,|dz|\le C\frac{R^{3/2}}{R^2-1}\stackrel{R\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0,
$$
$$
\left|\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{e^{(1/2+i)\log z}}{z^2+1}\,dz\right|\le \int_{\gamma_r}\frac{e^{1/2 \log|z|-\arg(z)}}{1-r^2}\,|dz|\le Cr^{3/2}\stackrel{r\to 0}\longrightarrow 0.
$$ Thus it follows by residue theorem
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} f(z)dz +\int_{\gamma_{-\epsilon}} f(z)dz\right) =2\pi i\left(\text{res}_{z=i}f(z)+\text{res}_{z=-i}f(z)\right).
$$
We find$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} f(z)dz=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}e^{i\ln x}}{x^2+1}\,dx,
$$
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\gamma_{-\epsilon}} f(z)dz=-\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{(1/2+i)(\ln x+2\pi i)}}{x^2+1}\,dx=+e^{-2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}e^{i\ln x}}{x^2+1}\,dx.
$$ And also
$$
\text{res}_{z=i}f(z)=\frac{e^{(1/2+i)\frac{\pi i}{2}}}{2i}=\frac{e^{-\pi/2+\pi i/4}}{2i},
$$
$$
\text{res}_{z=-i}f(z)=-\frac{e^{(1/2+i)\frac{3\pi i}{2}}}{2i}=-\frac{e^{-3\pi/2+3\pi i/4}}{2i}.
$$
Thus the given integral is
$$
\frac{\pi}{1+e^{-2\pi}}\Re\left(e^{-\pi/2+\pi i/4}-e^{-3\pi/2+3\pi i/4}\right)=\frac{\pi\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2})}{\sqrt{2}\cosh(\pi)}\sim 0.4805.
$$
(I found that this value coincides with the integral numerically by wolframalpha.)

Comment: This is exactly what I meant to do. Can you please elaborate how you bounded $\gamma_r$ ?( For the small $r$)
In addition - I think the factor outside the integral of $\gamma_{-\epsilon}$ is supposed to be $e^{2\pi i(\frac{1}{2}+i)}$

Comment: @Sar Since $r\to 0$, the term $1/(1-r^2)$ is bounded as $r\to 0$. And similarly, since $\arg(z)$ is bounded, $e^{\log|z|/2 -\arg(z)}$ is bounded by $Ce^{\log r/2}=C\sqrt{r}$. Finally, length of $\gamma_r$ is about $2\pi r$. This gives the bound $Cr^{3/2}$. I hope this makes it clear :)

Comment: Yes, Much simpler than I thought . Thank you very much !
Is it true what I commented on the factor on the previous comment? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Sar Oh, you are also right. Since $e^{2\pi i(1/2+i)}=e^{\pi i-2\pi}=-e^{-2\pi}$, both results are correct.

Answer (score 4):

Integrating by parts twice, we get
$$
\int_0^\infty\cos(x)\,e^{-ax}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a}{a^2+1}\tag1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}\cos(\log(x))}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{e^{2x}+1}e^{3x/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{e^{2x}+1}e^{x/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{e^x+e^{-x}}\left(e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag4\\
&=\int_0^\infty\cos(x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(e^{-(4k+1)x/2}+e^{-(4k+3)x/2}\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag5\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left[\frac{k+\frac14}{\left(k+\frac14\right)^2+\frac14}+\frac{k+\frac34}{\left(k+\frac34\right)^2+\frac14}\right]\tag6\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi{\sqrt2}\frac{\cosh(\pi/2)}{\cosh(\pi)}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: substitute $x\mapsto e^x$
$(3)$: substitute $x\mapsto-x$
$(4)$: average $(2)$ and $(3)$ and apply symmetry
$(5)$: expand into power series
$(6)$: apply $(1)$
$(7)$: use $(7)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3088133)